# Группировка в регулярных выражениях java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите. Есть код с сайта. 
Почему m.group(1) выдает Найдено значение: Крещение Руси произошло в 98
Почему m.group(2) выдает Найдено значение: 8

```
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class k4 {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
  // Строка для сканирования, чтобы найти шаблон
  String str = "Крещение Руси произошло в 988 году! Не так ли?";
  String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

  // Создание Pattern объекта
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Создание matcher объекта


  Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Найдено значение: " + m.group(0));
     System.out.println("Найдено значение: " + m.group(1));
     System.out.println("Найдено значение: " + m.group(2));
  }else {
     System.out.println("НЕ СОВПАДАЕТ");
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберём данное регулярное выражение :
В интерпретаторе regex джавы пишут `\\` вместо `\` (как в большинстве языков), я разбиру как в большинстве.

```
(.*)(\d+)(.*)
```

`.` - любой символ | `.*` - строка из любых символов кроме `\n`, количество от `0 до бесконечности` (жадный отбор строки).

`(.*)` - скобочки делают из внутреннего выражения группу, т.е. тот участок строки соответствующий подскобочному выражению в match выделится в отдельную группу.

`\d` - цифра, `\d+` - строка из любых цифр, количество от `1 до бесконечности`

`(\d+)` - группа состоящая только из цифр.

А теперь разберём, что мы имеем для `(.*)(\d+)(.*)`:

> Крещение Руси произошло в 988 году! Не так ли?

Сначало выражение жадно читает абсолютно все символы, коих может быть от 0 до беск. После этой части  у нас должны быть цифры, коих есть от 1 до беск. и опять символы тупо до конца строки, которые сформируют 3 группу. Учитывая, что первая группа жадная, то она решает, что после неё как минимум должна идти одна цифра, она как истинная жадина забирает всё, что плохо лежит, т.е. 98 и оставляет 1 восьмёрку для 2 группы.

Противоположность жадности - лень (лень забирать, что-нибудь). 1 группа знает, что 2 группа начинается с цифр и встретив их она ленится идти дальше и передаёт бразды правления 2 группе.

Т.е. правильная запись регулярки `(.*?)(\d+)(.*)`.

`?` - указатель, что набирание элементов ленивое.